# Why does making the text move in marquee style to the left dosent get to the end of the left side?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have in my form two button and a label and a timer control.
In the timer tick event i did:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mode == "Left-to-Right")
    {
        if (this.Width == xpos)
        {
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, ypos);
            xpos = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xpos, ypos);
            xpos += 2;
        }
    }
    else if (mode == "Right-to-Left")
    {
        if (xpos == 0)
        {
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Width, ypos);
            xpos = this.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xpos, ypos);
            xpos -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Then a button click event:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xpos = label2.Location.X;
    ypos = label2.Location.Y;
    mode = "Left-to-Right";
    timer2.Start();
}
```

And a button click event:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xpos = label2.Location.X;
    ypos = label2.Location.Y;
    mode = "Right-to-Left";
    timer2.Start();
}
```

When i click on button2 to make it move left to right it's working good when the text get to the end of the right side the text is like moving inside out of the bound/border then return from the left side.

But when i click the button right to left once the text get to the end on the left bound/border the text is vanish/disapear for second and then start to mvoe from the original position it was. Why it's not acting like it does on button2 left to right ?

EDIT**

This is what i changed:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mode == "Left-to-Right")
    {
        if (this.Width == xpos)
        {
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, ypos);
            xpos = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xpos, ypos);
            xpos += 2;
        }
    }
    else if (mode == "Right-to-Left")
    {
        if (xpos < -label2.Width)
        {
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Width, ypos);
            xpos = this.ClientSize.Width - label2.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xpos, ypos);
            xpos -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Several mistakes.  this.Width includes the borders, use this.ClientWidth instead.  To make it symmetric, you need `if (xpos < -label2.Width)` instead of `if (xpos == 0)` to allow it to scroll off the window.  And restart it at `xpos = this.ClientWidth - label2.Width`

Comment: Hans look at my question edited with what i did now stil not working good enough.

Comment: Now you are just adding bugs.  Swap the two statements and use this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xpos, ypos);

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if `this.Width` is an odd number. Try changing this

```
if (this.Width == xpos)
```

to this:

```
if (this.Width >= xpos)
```

It is generally a good idea not to test changing numbers for equality. Test for `greater than` or for `less than` or for `greater or equal`.. This is called **defensive programming**, doesn't cost you anything and makes your code more robust.